# Is it possible to have the "IF" on a "select" statement or using "Case"?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have an IF statement that basically gives me concatenation of addresses if value for them is not null. as see below :

```
IF @Address1 IS NOT NULL
BEGIN       
    IF @Address2 IS NOT NULL SET @TotalAddress=ISNULL(@Address1, '')+CHAR(13)+@Address2
        ELSE SET @TotalAddress=@Address1;
    IF @Address3 IS NOT NULL SET @TotalAddress=ISNULL(@Address1, '')+CHAR(13)+ISNULL(@Address2, '')+CHAR(13)+ISNULL(@Address3, '')
    IF @Address4 IS NOT NULL SET @TotalAddress=ISNULL(@Address1, '')+CHAR(13)+ISNULL(@Address2, '')+CHAR(13)+ISNULL(@Address3, '')+CHAR(13)+ISNULL(@Address4, '')
END
```

I was wondering if I can have my code in select statement directly and grab address1,2 and 3 without creating a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this using CONCAT ,NULLIF , IIF and ISNULL

```
declare @address1 varchar(10)= NULL
declare @address2 varchar(10)= '39 Cox Street'
declare @address3 varchar(10)= NULL
declare @address4 varchar(10)= 'Chicago'


select
   iif(isnull(@address1,'') = '','',
   concat(@address1 + char(13),
   nullif(@address2,'') + char(13) ,
   nullif(@address3,'') + char(13),
   nullif(@address4,'') + char(13)))
```

demo found here http://rextester.com/live/OMP74388

Comment: This isn't the same functionality as the if ... begin ... end code (If the first value is NULL no further concatenation is performed).

Comment: Thanks  a lot @maSTAShuFu that works but one other possible scenario is for records that are null for address 1 and  has values for address2 and 3.
Would it be possible to cover this scenario as well?

Comment: I think I got it, I just changed the first line to nullif(@address1,' ') = ...........

Comment: yes, original i put nullif to address1 to convert it but since your OP states that if address1 is null then don't do anything.

Comment: Thank you so much @maSTAShuFu that gave me result that I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use if condition. You can achieve the desired output using `ISNULL()` and `NULLIF()` function.

Try this

```
DECLARE @address1 varchar(50)= NULL,
        @address2 varchar(50)= '39 Cox Street',
        @address3 varchar(50)= '',
        @address4 varchar(50)= 'Chicago',
        @TotalAddress varchar(max)

SET @TotalAddress = ISNULL(NULLIF(@Address1, '') + CHAR(13), '') 
                    +ISNULL(NULLIF(@Address2, '') + CHAR(13), '')
                    +ISNULL(NULLIF(@Address3, '') + CHAR(13), '')
                    +ISNULL(NULLIF(@Address4, ''), '')

PRINT @TotalAddress
```

Comment: That will add the `CHAR(13)` even the variable `IS NULL`

Comment: In addition to what @Sami said, I wonder what the purpose of `NULLIF` is here. If `x` is anything but an empty string, then `NULLIF(x, '')` is equal to `x`. And if `x` is an empty string, then `NULLIF(x, '')` returns null... but you have that expression wrapped in an `ISNULL`, which turns the null right back into an empty string. So isn't `ISNULL(NULLIF(x, ''))` exactly equal to `ISNULL(x, '')`, or am I missing something?

Comment: @maSTAShuFu: Excuse me, I have took only variable declaration part, right. Initially you and me post the answer almost at the same time. Come-on i have not copied your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way using `IIF()`:

```
SELECT IIF(@Address1 IS NULL, '', @Address1 + CHAR(13))+
       IIF(@Address2 IS NULL, '', @Address2 + CHAR(13))+
       IIF(@Address3 IS NULL, '', @Address3 + CHAR(13))+
       IIF(@Address4 IS NULL, '', @Address4 + CHAR(13)) AS Result
```